# Hudson checkout gets stuck at 'git fetch'

Tags: git, hudson

I'm using git version 1.6.2.2.1669.g7eaf8 
with Hudson Git plugin 0.7.3 on Hudson 1.314

When I trigger a build, Hudson does a git fetch, but it never returns.   I had one stuck there for 14 days before I killed it.

The console output - it just sits here for days on end:

```
    Started by user anonymous

    Checkout:workspace / C:\hudson\jobs\Group1-git\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@3d858159

    Last Build : #63

    Checkout:workspace / C:\hudson\jobs\Group1-git\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@3d858159

    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

    Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git/devl.git

    [workspace] $ git.cmd fetch ssh://git@git/devl.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Here's the stack trace for the thread that is stuck:

```
Executor #0 for master

"Executor #0 for master" Id=35 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Native Method)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:166)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:102)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:486)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:231)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$000(GitSCM.java:56)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:373)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:358)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:649)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:633)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:358)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:830)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:314)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:266)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:938)
    at hudson.model.Build.run(Build.java:112)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:93)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:118)

    Number of locked synchronizers = 1
    - java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@4d9d8bfe
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could git be waiting for input - perhaps an ssh password or keyphrase to access the private key?

Comment: actually, it's waiting for approval to add the host to the known_hosts file.   Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this issue?

Comment: When you first estanlish a ssh connection to an unknown system, SSH must ask for permission to add this System's Unique key to its known hosts file. This requires user interaction causing the Git checkout to "hang" - http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rrmfW8HGbyQJ:amath.colorado.edu/computing/unix/sshknownhosts.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk