# Hudson Build is Frozen Using GitHub

Tags: git, hudson

I am running Hudson and the build just froze at the following line:

Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:azamsharp/EStudy.git

`[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" fetch -t git@github.com:azamsharp/EStudy.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

The build is started by anonymous.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

The log is reading as follows:

anonymous
        
      
    
  
  5
  FAILURE
  3895
  windows-1252
  false
  
  C:\Users\azamsharp.hudson\jobs\EStudy Application\workspace
  1.341

Comment: Duplicate of my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093927/hudson-checkout-gets-stuck-at-git-fetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two account systems here: the set of OS accounts on the machine hosting Hudson, and then there are the set of accounts that Hudson uses to allow access to the webapp.  When you see "started by anonymous" that is referring to Hudson's user account system.  Hudson's internal accounts are irrelevant to this problem, as they only control access to Hudson's UI and do not interact with executing jobs.

The OS account matters a lot, as ssh is configured to look for host keys and id keys in the .ssh folder of $HOME.  You may have passwordless ssh working with your own login, but it also needs to be setup for the user the Hudson service runs as.

Check ssh setup for the user Hudson is running as.  If you are running it as a service, it will be the SERVICE user.

**The Hudson user (the system account) probably doesn't have passwordless ssh setup, or if it does it might be trying to interactively ask to accept the host key.**  One quick test would be to restart Hudson using the standalone mode.  This will be running as you, so you can see if the freezing issue goes away

```
java -jar hudson.war
```

The easist way to fix this is to log in as that user and setup ssh until it works.  If it is difficult to become that user, you will want to copy the authorized_keys file and id_rsa or id_dsa file to the .ssh folder of the home directory of that user.

I suggest you separate the service issues from the rest.  So try running hudson in standalone mode first - turn off the service and just launch it from a command window.   See if that works.  If it does, then you know there is a configuration problem with your service account.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by SERVICE user. I have the following accounts on my Win 7 machine. 
1) azamsharp 
2) Administrator 
3) Local Service
4) Network service 

I use azamsharp since that is the only account I know the password. 

When I try to use the "Build Now" option of hudson web interface I get the following error: 

Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:azamsharp/EStudy.git

[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" fetch -t git@github.com:azamsharp/EStudy.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: Also, I don't have any password or phrase to connect to my Git server.

Comment: One other thing to note is that when I start the build it says "started by anonymous".

Comment: I don't find any .ssh folder in .hudson directory. I found the ssh-slaves folder inside the hudson plugins. 

http://ct.go2map.com/map_sogou/lushu/hudson/plugins/ssh-slaves/help_privatekey.html

Comment: ssh-slaves is independent of your git issue.   The '.ssh' folder should be in under the $HOME directory.   So your first step would be to see what $HOME is set to, by looking at the Hudson config page, where it should have a listing of environment variables and system properties.